# How to find the size of an Iterable Object?

Tags: java, iterator

I'm in process of writing an MR Job. But I'm stuck with an Issue related to an Iterable object. I need to find its size. I casted it to a List object,but that was wrong.(List can be casted to Iterable, but cannot do reversal.) There is another way, i.e. by using an Iterator for the object and incrementing a counter for each value. But that is not an optimal solution. Can anybody suggest a better way?.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please write your code here so that we can check it out.

Comment: This question doesn't really feel like a duplicate of the one linked in the edit

Answer (score 15):

The `Collection` interface provides a `size()` method and it extends `Iterable`. If your iterator happens to come from a collection, you can ask it for its size, otherwise you are out of luck, you simply have to iterate till the end.

Here's a hack that implements this:

```
public int size(Iterable<?> it) {
  if (it instanceof Collection)
    return ((Collection<?>)it).size();

  // else iterate

  int i = 0;
  for (Object obj : it) i++;
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to go through the iterator and count the items.
For instance,

```
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
            count++;
        }
```

This is not very clean but iterator is used with the purpose of iterate and does not provide any specific api for that.

But, where is the iterator created? If it comes from another object, for instance a Collection object, you can determine the size of the source and not the iterator itself.

Comment: This will not work in case of an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator doesn't have a size() on it, but some of the Collections from which Iterator has been derived has a size(), like java.util.LinkedList.size(). So, you may have to iterate in some cases.

Comment: The problem is with the reducer function:

protected final void reduce(final Text key,    final Iterable<Text> values, final Context context)    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
......
}
Here the "values" is an Iterable Object. I need to find its size without iterating.But that is not possible since is not a collection object.I need to do some other operation after finding the size. If I'm iterating over this object, then after the iteration, the iterator will be pointing to its last value. I need to reset it. So I'm using a ResettableIterator so that after iteration I can reset it.

Comment: You should be able to ask for an `iterator()` as many times as you want from an `Iterable`, that's why you get an `Iterable` and not an `Iterator` in `reduce`. So `Iterator<Text> a = values.iterator(), b = values.iterator();` is perfectly valid and they should be independent as long as you don't call `remove()` on either.