# Resetting Iterable Object

Tags: mapreduce, iterable

I am writing a MR job where in the reducer side, I need to check the size of Iterable before doing anything. Someone did asked the same question long back([How to find the size of an Iterable Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412798/how-to-find-the-size-of-an-iterable-object/17648708#17648708)) but the solutions given are not working.Since the Iterable doesnt have a size() method, please suggesst me how to do it.
I tried the following options.

1. Tried to get a iterator object from iterable, but got following typecast
   error. Same error with ResettableIterator. `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.ReduceContext$ValueIterator cannot be cast to java.util.ListIterator`
2. If i iterate to the end of the Iterable object to get size, then
   How can I go back to the start of the index.
3. `if(values instanceof Collection){
           return ((Collection)values).size();
       }`
    this doesnt get hit as the values is of different type.

Please help me with some sample code. This issue has really taken a lot of time.
Thanks a lot.!!

Answer (score 0):

1. `Iterator iterator = Use values.iterator();` to get iterator.
2. Store values in `List` or some other data structure and then iterate over it.